# Leaks when the app terminates

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, memory-management, memory-leaks

Should I handle leaks when the application terminates, or is it more efficient to let the system handle them? I'm thinking that the system will be reclaiming all the memory anyway, so wouldn't additional efforts to free it be overhead?

Comment: I believe system reclaims the memory only when memory leaks are there. If your application has returned all the resources acquired then the system has nothing to do. So, there is no overhead.

Comment: How do you handle leaks after the fact? Leaks are called leaks because you cannot reclaim the original reference to the lost memory location - "the reference leaks away".

Comment: @jsn, I can't *handle* them, but I can update my code in such a way that leaks are not produced. They are currently produced because of some singletons that I'm only going to need for the lifetime of the application.

Comment: @Mahesh, but if the application quits, then the system should simply mark *all* its memory as free, without any extra cycles on my part to do it, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Radu singletons do NOT cause leaks, in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: @Radu, this situation is not about handling leaks then. No offense, but this topic is then regarding proper c coding conventions and techniques. You should never, ever produce leaks. ESPECIALLY on an embedded device (iOS tag). Embedded devices may not reclaim all memory assigned to a program (OS dependent - Windows does it by default).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, they don't, but the memory I `malloc()`-ed in them will, unless I `free()` it.

Comment: @Radu no, they won't. Once an application quits, all memory associated will be marked as available again by the OS, so you have nothing to work about.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII This is OS dependent. Several embedded OS's (iOS tag) may not reclaim all application assigned memory!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, that's my case. The Instruments app informs me that the memory is leaked. This memory I allocated with `malloc()`. So the question is, is it good practice to make the proper `free()` calls, or is this overhead?

Comment: @Radu, calling `free` is highly limited overhead, if at all.

Comment: @jsn, so, better safe than sorry...

Comment: @Rady exactly. You should never be concerned about overhead when trying to follow proper and expected coding conventions, such as freeing any memory when you do not need it.

Comment: ..and you should not be concerned with proper and expected coding conventions when faced with, say, shutting down an app with many threads in changing states. I'm afraid that many such conventions are just not sane if applied to complex apps.  As bbum/paxdiablo, (I like that name:), say, it's easy to fall into the trap of inflicting a lot of pain on yourself for no, or negative, gain.  It's like 'always cleanly shut down threads' and 'always use references instead of pointers' - a world of suffering and frustration awaits..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote by [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo):

> All of the operating systems that I have knowledge of will reclaim conventional memory that had been allocated. That's because the allocation generally comes from a processes private address space which will be reclaimed on exit.

As far I'm aware this also applies to iOS.

Apple might however reject your Application. Memory leaks alone are generally no reason to reject application, they might however be the drop that makes the bucket overflow. Proper memory management is good practice and should always be pursued.

Comment: Indeed, that's what the question is about, which is the proper memory management practice. As jsn points out in the comments, the overhead should be minimal.

Comment: By "proper memory management" I mean no leaks occur during execution and / or exit. Proper memory management characterizes good programming skills, the developer knows what he / she is doing. During review I generally insist on fixing significant memory leaks. The overhead is indeed minimal.

Comment: So, how to cope with singletons upon termination?

Comment: @Anne, I completely agree that everyone should follow best practices. For my case, it's really just 1 line of code. I simply wanted to know which is the proper thing to do - free or not free. I'll free.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no reason to try and free all memory when your app terminates.**

Doing so is a waste of CPU cycles.

Certainly, you might need a "shutdown" phase that'll persist some state, but your code must also assume that the "shutdown" codepath may not be run.

The system will reclaim *all* resources allocated by an application when the app is terminated, regardless of how it is terminated.

In fact, the UIKit (iOS) and AppKit (OS X) both take lots of shortcuts during application termination that cause lots of memory to still be allocated when the app terminates.  This is done exactly for responsiveness reasons;  when the user requests an app to be quit, it should quit very quickly.

(And I can't really think of a modern multi-tasking, task isolating, OS that doesn't automatically reclaim resources on process termination.)

Comment: 'I can't really think of a modern multi-tasking, task isolating, OS that doesn't automatically reclaim resources on process termination' - just as well, as just about every non-trivial app I've ever developed relies on this, especially the multithreaded ones, (that's about all of them).  Unless there is a override, ('all DB connections must be closed and all files flushed on app termination' in the spec), I don't bother with any explicit termination code - and I cannot have any shutdown code problems if there is no shutdown code :)

Answer (score 1):

All applications (processes) run in their own private memory space.  The operating system manages this and always knows exactly what 'physical' memory has been allocated to the process.  When the process exits, it is able to completely recover all of the used memory.

Therefore, if your application is going to exit you don't need to do any memory management or cleanups (the same is true for file accesses or network connections and so forth, though in these cases it may be in your best interests to clean up).

However, your application should never 'leak' memory.

**A leak is when you allocate a chunk of memory and then lose all references to it within your running program.**

A singleton is not a leak and Instruments will not flag it as a leak.

So, if you have something like this:

```
static NSString *aStaticString = nil;

+ (void)aFunction {
    aStaticString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"aFunction"];
}
```

This is not a leak.  So lets say you also have another function:

```
+ (void)anotherFunction {
    aStaticString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"anotherFunction"];
}
```

Now, assuming you're using ARC, calling these functions will not cause leaks.  The compiler/runtime knows to manage the NSString allocations, and as the aStaticString variable changes, deallocates the old memory.

So given this, how do you get leaks?  Generally it will be due to circular references.  For example:

```
+ (void)aBadFunction {
    NSMutableDictionary *aDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [aDict addObject:aDict forKey:@"aCircularReference"];
}
```

Here, aDict is created (allocated), then a reference to itself is added to it.  When the function returns, the memory gets leaked as your program no longer has any reference to the aDict variable (if the function gets called again a new completely different aDict variable will get created).  Now normally ARC would ensure aDict gets deallocated when the function exits, but in this case it can't as there is a reference to it **in the object itself**.

Generally circular references like this are more complex, but the principle is the same.

Comment: +1 for 'A leak is when you allocate a chunk of memory and then lose all references to it within your running program'.  This is obviously bad and should be fixed. It's quite a different case when leaving memory that you DO know about for the OS to clean up - that's just normal practice.  In multiThreaded apps, where some objects are in use by threads running on other cores, it's almost impossible to explicitly free up all memory allocated - you have to leave it to the OS.  Unlike user code, the OS can easily stop all threads before deallocating any process memory or other resources.

Answer (score 0):

You should always free memory, however, see comments below:

There is a difference between:

```
int main() {

    int* i = malloc(5);
    ... // do stuff here
    return 0; // i "leaked" here, not that serious, a lot of programmers will skip freeing `i` before return

}
```

and:

```
int main() {

    int* i;
    for(int j = 0; j < 5000; j++)
        i = malloc(5); // you leaked 5 bytes 5000 times, very serious, DO NOT DO THIS
    // the 24KB here will most likely be reclaimed later, HOWEVER
    // what if j changes? what if you have more loops? you may run of memory, especially on an embedded device!
    ... // do stuff here
    return 0;

}
```

Just follow one single rule: never be concerned about overhead when dealing with proper C memory management (C coding conventions).

so do this:

```
int main() {

    int* i;
    for(int j = 0; j < 5000; j++) {
        i = malloc(5);
        ... // do stuff with i here
        free(i); // you are not leaking anything =D         
    }
    ... // do stuff here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I misrepresented what "leaks" are in my code... I'm allocating some memory, doing things with it during the lifetime of the app, and then the app quits. It's definitely nothing like example #2, it's more likely like example #1, but for a lot more memory than 5 bytes. The Instruments app though still marks them as "leaks", since, logically, they are leaks, if I'm never freeing them...

Comment: @Radu You are right, it is still a leak. Like I said in my #1 comments, most programmers will skip this. I would free. Up to you.

Comment: It's not a leak if you haven't lost it!  Leaving allocated memory ,that you still have a reference to, for the OS to clean up is just fine.  In many multithreaded apps, it's preferable to the horrifying alternative of trying to stop threads in unknown states, perhaps running on other cores or about to become ready at any moment. An OS can do that easily before deallocating memory, user code cannot.  A non-increasing, explainable 'leak' report from Valgrind etc. is just not a problem.